# How to use an OR in a filter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-options

I have an unordered list that is being filtered on when a select option is selected. My problem is that when 'ALL' is selected nothing displays because the value does not match the `item.status` of any of my list items. Is there a way of adding `||` which will then filter on `item.status` or 'ALL'?

Below are the values that are in the select. One of these values is also referenced for each list item as `item.status`

```
app.value('filterSavedList', pageOptions = [
    {
        value: 'ALL',
        label: 'All'
    },
    {
        value: 'NEW',
        label: 'Not started'
    },
    {
        value: 'STARTED',
        label: 'In progress'
    },
    {
        value: 'COMPLETED',
        label: 'Completed'
    }
]);
```

My select and my unordered list.

```
    <select ng-model="filter" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in status">
    </select>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in assignments | filter: { status : filter }">
       //do stuff                     
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Setting the value to `''` should do the trick, AFAIR.

Comment: I did try that earlier, but it adds a blank option at the start of the select options before selecting a valid option. Once selected, the blank option disappears...

Comment: It does that because you haven't initialized the select model (filter) to any of the status values. See http://plnkr.co/edit/mJtQnwA3aQhpT4WN62jj?p=preview. $scope.filter is supposed to be one of the four values, but it's a 5th one. So angular adds an option to display this 5th value.

Comment: great answer! Annoyed I missed that! Type it up as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set the status value to `''` (empty string), and make sure `filter` (i.e. the model of the select box) is initialized to one of the 4 values (i.e. initialized to `''`, if the option *All* must be pre-selected)

See http://plnkr.co/edit/mJtQnwA3aQhpT4WN62jj?p=preview for a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom filter that does normal filtering by property and also takes care of the `ALL` possibility in `status`:

```
.filter('filterStatus', function () {
    return function (items, status) {
        if(status === 'ALL') {
            return items;
        }
        else {
            var itemsToReturn = [];
            for(var i=0,x=items.length;i<x;i++) {
                if(items[i].status === status) {
                    itemsToReturn.push(items[i]);
                }
            }
            return itemsToReturn;
        }
    };
});
```

Then in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in assignments | filterStatus: filter">
        <!-- do stuff -->                     
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks good but I think i will go with the answer by JB Nizet in the comments on my question. Thanks!